# Firebase Problem to write data when creating account

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Basically, i want users to create account and write data like Name, User, etc. to firestore database. But i don't know the rules for that.

> W/Firestore( 9927): (24.5.0) [Firestore]: Write failed at Users/FPhBBFybqXfCuXtFYTVO: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
> I/flutter ( 9927): [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

Actually my rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow read, write, update, delete: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Rules don't do anything on their own, but only get activated when triggered by your code. Please edit your question to show the [minimal code with which any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In that code, make sure to check that your application meets the requirement that your rules set, i.e. check if there is a current user right before you access the database.

Answer (score 1):

try this rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Frank van Puffelen stated in comments :

> Rules don't do anything on their own, but only get activated when triggered by your code.

To achieve this you need to have a document already present in the `users` collection. One way of doing this is using [**Firebase Authentication trigger on user creation**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation) since firebase functions run on Trusted Environment Thus firebase admin sdk does not follow firestore security rules.

Here is the sample firebase onCreate Auth Trigger.

**functions/index.ts**:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

export const onCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  functions.logger.log("User created : ", user);
  const userDoc = admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user.uid);
  await userDoc.set({
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
// you can add extra details too
  });
})
```

Since this trigger will be activated as soon as the user is created the next time, when users want to read or update their information, they can do so using the following `security rules` through the Firebase SDK on the client side:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Notice we are only allowing read for logged in user’s but for users to write we are comparing `user.uid` against the document Id as this is how we have written our Auth trigger.

Reference: [**Firebase Authentication triggers**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) and [**Writing conditions for Cloud Firestore Security Rules**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
allow create: if request.auth != null;
```

For this, Users won't be able to create the Document if they are not authorised, e.g logged in or account created.

For more understanding on rules, visit

[FireStore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)

Comment: I removed this line and it's not working yet.

Comment: I think the problem is that i'm trying to write before creating account, but i don't know how to solve it with rules.

Comment: Need to check if the order in the code. Once successfully logged in, then only create the document and write into it. Make sure you have successfully logged in to  Firebase. Removing the above line allows you to CREATE document even when not logged in. But the 2nd rule i.e to WRITE in the document, needs the user to logged in.